# CDF for a truncated poisson distribution

Tags: matlab, probability, truncate, cdf

Hi Iam looking for  the cumulative distribution function for truncated poisson random variable. I can find it for the regular "poisson cdf", MATLAB gives this:

p = poisscdf(x,lambda) returns the Poisson cdf at each value in x using the corresponding mean parameters in lambda

Is there an analogue to a truncated poisson poisson distribution ?

Comment: Well, for a truncated CDF you just take the truncated _x_  interval and scale it up so that the maximum value of the CDF (at the upper endpoint of the interval) is `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest first using the Matlab truncate function to adjust your distribution:

```
pd = makedist('poiss')
trunc = truncate(pd,1,3)
```

for Poisson, it can only be positive.

set a discrete range:

```
x = 0:.1:4;
distribution = pdf(trunc,x);
cummulative = cdf(trunc,x);
```

alternatively, you could integrate the pdf function using matlab integrate

Comment: is it possible to truncate it to the left , for example only at zero?

Comment: yes you can, but see the restrictions based on the type of distribution, for poiss, it has to be 0 or above I believe.